# JS/jQuery - set scroll bar of side nav bar to certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side nav bar which looks like this:

```css
.scroll-box {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 128px;
}
.filler {
  height: 256px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.selector {
  background-color: #369;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .1s !important;
}
.bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
.label {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #707070;
}
.active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #369;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-box">
  <div class="label">Dates</div>
  <div class="filler">
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector active" id="today">15-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
    <div class="selector">4-Aug-16</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get it so that when the page loads, it automatically centers the view of the side nav bar to the `today` id element. I've tried putting `myUrl#today` but that changes the entire page scroll, which I do not want. I

**I only want the scroll in the side nav bar to change it's position and center on the `#today` bit.** Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I am willing to use jQuery and JS as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use jQuery code such as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // when document is ready
  // first check if #today is defined in HTML
  // the $('') is the jQuery selector of to select an element
  // $('#today') means select an element with the ID "today"
  // the .length attribute is default javascript attribute to check 
  //     how many of elements selected has existed
  if($('#today').length > 0){
    // the offset() function is a jQuery function that is used for check the
    //    relative distance from the border of current element to its parent
    var distance_to_top = $('#today').offset().top;
    var top_label_height = $('.label').height();
    var distance_to_scroll = distance_to_top - top_label_height - 8; 
    // 8 px is body margin on jsfiddle
    // scrollTop() function is another jQuery function to scroll an     
    //     overflow element
    $('.filler').scrollTop(distance_to_scroll);
  }
});
```

find the offset of the today element relative to its parent, then minus the label height because the label will cover on top of the #today. the scroll to top

The demo can be found at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bawfba6k/2/)

Comment: thank you! not completely sure how this works but it does!

Comment: @4lackof, I have just added a bit more comment, so you can get some basic ideas how the jQuery code works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can do. (I can't test it right now...).

Basically, we get every element of the div that doesn't have the id "today" and we add the height of those elements. When we finally reach "today", we set the scrollbar to the height of every past elements added together and go out of the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = 0;
    $(".filler *").each(function () {
        if($(this).is("#today"))
        {
            return false; //to get out of the .each
        }
        else
        {
            height += $(this).height();
        }
    })
    $( "div.demo" ).scrollTop(height); //set the scrollbar
});
```